# Abrir modal en el sitio que hago click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular, bootstrap

Tengo una tabla con varias filas, quiero que al hacer click en cada fila se abra una modal para confirmar en este caso el borrado de la fila, pero quiero que al hacer click esa modal aparezca en la fila que he clickeado, no logro obtener el eje Y para posicionar mi modal

```css
div.delete-modal {
    right: 50px;
    top: 500px;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Modal -->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog delete-modal">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>


<table class="default">
  <tr>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Veo que estas usando bootstrap 5 **pero** con atributos `data-` del 4 o inferior. Los atributos `data-` del bootstrap 5 empiezan por `data-bs-` para no confundirlos con atributos de plugins o personalizados, por lo tanto para que te abran deberias cambiarlos (en tu snippet no funcionan, por eso lo digo)

Comment: @masterguru muchas, gracias ya está solucionado el problema que me comentaste, ya se abren las modales